# Use Android Phone Camera As Web Cam with OpenCV/C++

Tags: c++, opencv

I need a Mobile camera as webcam. I need to further process the camera video for my openCV application. But the softwares available for this purpose lacks required documentation of the api. (I mean how to access the phone camera interface) So can anyone give me good advice for this scenario.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, that it's not actually a matter of openCV. I assume, that the application will run on the PC. You have two options:

1. Attempt to interface with phone's camera using device-specific drivers. Maybe some of them support such feature.
2. Write an application for your mobile, which will stream the video through WiFi, Bluetooth or in another way. Then write a set of drivers, which will attempt to retrieve the video feed and provide to the OS as a webcam.

Third option involves recording the video on the mobile and then transferring it to the PC, but I guess, that it's not an option.

Comment: Off course that's the way this thing is gonna work. But my project is on openCV. So i basically want to know is there a good solution available.......

Comment: That's quite doubtful. There is no generic solution to connecting a mobile to PC as a webcam. It is not an openCV matter, but a matter of the OS seeing the mobile as a webcam. Also, have you considered problems arising from different mobile vendors and models? Each one has different way of exchanging data with PC (I mean, contacts, calendar etc.), so likely they'll all have different ways of sharing video feed (if that's even possible).

Comment: this vendor diversity problem won't be there if I use a client in that phone.Let me explain there will be a client side on phone n server side on pc. these two component do whatever they want.. But I just need a interface to the camera stream. I'm asking for a solution of this type.

Comment: Ok, but where's the problem. In capturing video from the camera and supplying it to the client? Transferring from the client to server? Passing from the server to an application?

Comment: passing from server to application.

Comment: I have no knowledge to OpenCV, so please understand. But I guess, that you want to provide it with captured frames, right? So actually it's just a matter of passing data from a program to another, what can be done with generic system techniques such as named pipes or TCP/IP, is that true? If not, where's the OpenCV involvement here?

Answer (score 2):

To make it work, we first need a mobile client. You can download "IP webcam" app on your android phone. Configure the port(for example: 2333) and start server.

If you computer and mobile connect to the same local network, you can type the ip address shown on your phone app on your computer's web browser. That should be ok.
In this way, the stream is transferred via wifi which is slow.

To improve the speed, you can connect via USB. We are going to redirect TCP stream over USB. Turn on debug mode on your android device and install android ADB tools on your computer. To forward the stream, the syntax is:

```
adb forward <local> <remote>
for example:
./adb forward tcp:5555 tcp:2333
```

forwarded your phone's `192.168.XX.XX:2333` to your computer's `http://localhost:5555/`

Then you can use this link.

To use in your OpenCV project, try the follow example:

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <iostream>

int main(int, char**) {
    cv::VideoCapture vcap;
    cv::Mat image;

    const std::string videoStreamAddress = "http://localhost:5555/video";
       //open the video stream and make sure it's opened
    if(!vcap.open(videoStreamAddress)) {
        std::cerr << "Error opening video stream or file" << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }

    for(;;) {
        vcap.read(image);
        cv::imshow("Output Window", image);

        if(cv::waitKey(1) >= 0) break;
    }

}
```